# Writing raw data "signature" to disk without corrupting filesystem

Tags: c++, ntfs, disk, raw-data

I am trying to create a program that will write a series of 10-30 letters/numbers to a disk in raw format (not to a file that the OS will read). Perhaps to make my attempt clearer, if you were to open the disk in a hex editor, you would see the 10-30 letters/numbers but a file manager such as Windows Explorer would not see it (because the data is not a file).

My goal is to be able to "sign" a disk with a series of characters and to be able to read and write that "signature" in my program. I understand NTFS signs its partitions with a NTFS flag as do other file systems and I have to be careful to not write my signature to any of those critical parts.

Are there any libraries in C++/C that could help me write at a low level to a disk and how will I know a safe sector to start writing my signature to? To narrow this down, it only needs to be able to write to NTFS, FAT, FAT32, FAT16 and exFAT file systems and run on Windows. Any links or references are greatly appreciated!

Edit: After some research, USB drives allow only 1 partition without applying hacking tricks that would unfold further problems for the user. This rules out the "partition idea" unfortunately.

Comment: How do you plan to stop the filesystem from overwriting your "signature"?

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but wouldn't it not bother it? If I wrote it at the "top/start" of the disk, it would place all new files added "below" it?

Comment: The filesystem can do whatever it wants with the disk.  That's why you have it.  In fact, the "top/start" of the disk is normally a place the file system is *most* active - its most basic data structures are normally stored there.

Comment: There are at least a couple of reasons why you don't want to do this. (1) Without "administrator" or "root" privileges, this is going to be impossible. (2) Even if you could write to disks in this way, any virus checker on the planet is going to flag your program as "evil". (3) How will your program adapt to future changes in filesystems?

Comment: What keeps it from overwriting the `MSDOS` or `NTFS` signature then? Is it possible to create a partition on the disk and place the signature in there?

Comment: Well, presumably the NTFS filesystem knows about its own signature and manages the data structures correctly.  You can certainly make a partition on the disk and put whatever you want in it.

Comment: Well, if you create your own whole *partition*, then you can put whatever you want in there (but you'll still need administrator/root access to be able to do raw writes). Are you looking to "sign" a *disk* or a *filesystem*? There's a big difference.

Comment: @GregHewgill I just fired up HxD hexeditor and wrote and ascii `A` to my flash drive, no antivirus rage there. Windows still recognizes the drive and will write to it. As for NTFS, correct me if I am wrong but I don't presume Windows will adapt a new fileing system anytime soon.

Comment: @GregHewgill I would like to "sign" the disk I think. Not sure the difference to be honest but the disk sounds more like my goals. I am not trying to tamper with the filesystem, simply write some data that is not recognized as a file.

Comment: @GregHewgill : you should post the partition idea as an answer. Cleanest way so far.

Comment: What's the reason to not have it in a file?  It's not like making a partition and stuffing your data in there is going to make it any harder to find.

Comment: It is part of a security tool. The purpose of the tool would be defeated if the attacker could simply delete the "key.txt" file. Writing raw data signatures requires a more skilled attacker to defeat it.

Comment: @CarlNorum : fair point. User99545: if someone wants to find your signature he will. If you want to protect from non tech savvy users, a file deep in the system or in the registry will be enough.

Comment: ... and your users might resent you repartitioning their disks.

Comment: @J.N. I need to write the data to the USB drive so I don't think the registry would be an option.

Comment: @CarlNorum : when putting it in the context of a USB drive it makes more sense. It's harder to hide a file on a partition with not so many files. It is probably a corporate drive.

Answer (score 2):

First, as the commenters said, you should look at *why* you're trying to do this, and see if it's really a good idea. Most apps which try to circumvent the normal UI the user has for using his/her computer are "bad", in various ways.

That said, you could try finding a well-known file which will always be on the system and has some slack in the block size for the disk, and write to the slack. I don't think most filesystems would care about extra data in the slack, and it would probably even be copied if the file happens to be relocated (more efficient to copy the whole block at the disk level).

Just a thought; dunno how feasible it would be, but seems like it *could* work in theory.

Answer (score 1):

Though I think this is generally a pretty poor idea, the obvious way to do it would be to mark a cluster as "bad", then use it for your own purposes.

Problems with that:

1. Marking it as bad is non-trivial (on NTFS bad clusters are stored in a file named something like `$BadClus`, but it's not accessible to user code (and I'm not even sure it's accessible to a device driver either).
2. There are various programs to scan for (and attempt to repair) bad clusters/sectors. Since we don't even believe this one is really bad, almost any of these that works at all will find that it's good and put it back into use.
3. Most of the reasons people think of doing things like this (like tying a particular software installation to a particular computer) are pretty silly anyway.
4. You'd have to scan through all the "bad" sectors to see if any of them contained your signature.

Comment: (4) is actually major; trying to read a true bad sector will often take a long time. The disk retries quite a bit before giving up. In the mean time, the disk typically won't do any other I/O.

Comment: @MSalters: Fair enough. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

This is very dangerous, however, zero-fill programs do the same thing so you can google how to wipe your hard drive with zero's in C++.

The hard part is finding a place you KNOW is unused and won't be used.